# react navigation content on top of header

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation

I am using **`react-navigation`** with custom header for all the screens. I am trying to design the app in such a way that the small top portion of the content view should overlay on top of the custom header.

I am using `options={{header: props => <CustomerHeader {...props} />}}` way of defining custom header for all the screens. I don't want to  use the header as a content for the screens though.

I tried using position absolute on the content but the content is always placed behind the header. Is there any way to place the content in top of the header?

Here's a snack with a minimal demo:

https://snack.expo.io/@tushark/absolute-header

Answer (score 0):

probably a bad design, but here's an idea.

https://snack.expo.io/@yoobit0616/absolute-header

Comment: But I will have many screens. Is this the good approach to go with? Other screens should also utilize the same header.

Comment: yeah, that's why i said it's probably a bad design lol....but that's the only way I can think of that can do what you want.